# Starting iterate from specific column

Tags: python, openpyxl

This is my .xslx file:

[data.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcWQU.png)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('/path/', read_only=True)
first_sheet = workbook.sheetnames()[0]
worksheet = workbook[first_sheet]

for row in worksheet:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

How can I start iteration from A4? I need to print `year` and `month` value.

Comment: Can you clarify what A4 is?

Comment: @SmallLegend I meant fourth column from data.xlsx

Comment: Assuming you want to read from A4 to A30, see if `for row in worksheet.iter_rows('A4:A30')` helps. Here is the documentation on [`iter_rows`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html#Worksheet.iter_rows).

Comment: `D1` would be the fourth column. `A4` is the fourth row.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`iter_rows`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/tutorial.html), either by specifying the offset or the range

```
for row in worksheet.iter_rows('A4:B9'):
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

Btw: `sheetnames()[0]` should be `sheetnames[0]` or `get_sheet_names()[0]`